# Error post installation ArcSDE for SQL server 2008

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-server, enterprise-geodatabase, sql-server, installation

I had a problem during post installation of ArcSDE for SQL server 2008,
and this is the message :

> The ArcSDE Repository was unsecessfully completed. would you like to
>   view this error?

then when I click on OK, what appears is:

> Connection to sde failed(0)

please can somebody help me ?

---

I am using ArcGIS 10,ArcSDE 10,SQL Server 2008 and for service pack I use SP2

Comment: Please update your question to include the exact version (with service pack) of ArcGIS you are using.

Comment: Make sure you can successfully connect to SQL Server using your account and that SQL server is running OK on it's own.