# ArcSDE post installation error?

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, sql-server, installation

I had a problem during post installation of ArcSDE for SQL server 2008, and this is the message :

The ArcSDE Repository was unsecessfully completed. would you like to view this error?
then when I click on OK, what appears is:

> Connection to sde failed(0)

Comment: This is the same as http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/102179/error-post-installation-arcsde-for-sql-server-2008 That has no answer but comments suggest some additional information that you should [edit] into your question..

Comment: What's your version of ArcGIS? in new version of arcgis  you can use create enterprise geodatabase tool to create sde geodatabase

Comment: In just three months the last version of ArcGIS which had an ArcSDE postinstaller will be Retired; it seems a bit late to be creating new geodatabases with that software. That error is associated with an incorrect or invalid password (newer databases enforce a password complexity requirement).